# Propagating time attribute after an interval join, to do window aggregation later

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am attempting to change query 4 (Average Price for a category) from [nexmark benchmark](https://datalab.cs.pdx.edu/niagara/pstream/nexmark.pdf) to produce an append only stream of average price for a category, using only flink sql as much as possible.
Query for the original description is available [here](https://github.com/nexmark/nexmark/blob/master/nexmark-flink/src/main/resources/queries/q4.sql) in the nexmark benchmark repository.

This query produces an updating stream. I would like to instead produce an append only stream.
My approach was

1. Do an [interval join](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#interval-joins) between auction and bid, group by bid and select the max price. This creates *sell price* for each item. This produces updates and deletes due to group by.
2. Convert [1] to a [windowed aggregate](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-agg/), in an attempt to convert [1] to an append only stream. Here I need a time attribute, and I am not sure how to propagate time attribute from [1] here.

**To summarize**, how can we propagate time attribute from an interval join, to do a window aggregation afterwards?

Here is the sql I used

```sql
WITH auction AS (
    Select dateTime SystemTime, auction.* from datagen2 where event_type = 1
),
bid AS(
    Select dateTime SystemTime, bid.* from datagen2 where event_type = 2
),
--Interval join.
MaxSellPricePerCategory AS (
select
    auction.id AuctionId,
    auction.category,
    max(bid.price) SellPrice,
    max(bid.SystemTime) BidSystemTime,
    max(bid.dateTime) LastBidTime
from
    auction
join
    bid
on
    auction.id = bid.auction
    --Add a condition on rowtime to make this a interval join
    and bid.SystemTime between auction.SystemTime and auction.SystemTime + INTERVAL '50' MINUTES
    --bid should be during the auction active time.
    and bid.dateTime between auction.dateTime and auction.expires
group by
    auction.id,
    auction.category
),
AverageSellPricePerWindow AS (
select
    window_start,
    category,
    AVG(SellPrice) AverageSellPriceInWindow
from
    TABLE(
        TUMBLE(TABLE MaxSellPricePerCategory, DESCRIPTOR(BidSystemTime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES)
    )
GROUP BY
    window_start,
    window_end,
    category
)

select * from AverageSellPricePerWindow;
```

It fails with below

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: The window function requires the timecol is a time attribute type, but is TIMESTAMP(3).
```

**Other approaches considered**

1. Use a [window join](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-join/). This requires the two stream's window to align (i.e. it requires equality condition on window_start and window_end). Business logic defines it as an overlapping interval.
2. Use an upsert sink. This works, but was not my final goal.

Comment: I think the issue here is not the join, but the `group by` in MaxSellPricePerCategory, which doesn't have a window_time. Max(bid.SystemTime) does not retain time attribute.